# Safari 9 and earlier chokes on ES6

Tags: javascript, safari

How can I use ES6 and still allow Safari 9 to load the rest of the Javascript without choking on just this bit?

```
    let audio;
$(".playAudio").on('click touchstart', function () {
    if(audio){
        audio.pause();
    }
    audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.setAttribute('src', $(this).attr('data-audio'));
    audio.currentTime = 0;
    audio.play();
});
```

Comment: Use Babel's polyfill: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/. It is included inside `babel-node` package.

Comment: Safari 9 will choke on *lots* of ES6 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES5 does not support the let keyword, to fix for older JS environments update `let audio` to `var audio`.